# How to start an activity Dialog

Tags: android

I have one activity which i am using for displaying Dialogs and as a normal layout.
So what i want to do is, sometimes i want to start activity as Theme Dialog and some times using setContentView.

I can't use `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">` in manifest file as it will always display activity as dialog.

So can we do it programmatic, i have also tried `setTheme()` method but it did't work.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the dialog/fullscreen style before starting the activity, you could add 2 subclasses and declare them in your manifest. Then you start one or the other depending on the desired style.